# Compile GTK+ with Cygwin

Tags: gtk, cygwin, compilation

I have created an application in linux with GTK2 as GUI. It uses some linux-specific headers (e.g. arpa/inet.h) so to run under Windows I have to compile it with Cygwin. I downloaded the latest installer and choose to install GTK2 and its dependencies. My program compiled fine. But it needs X server to be running! I has old-style, ugly graphics and it doesn't open in a different window, like all Windows' applications do, but inside X server's window. Because of this it can't be portable. I found [that guide](http://kemovitra.blogspot.com/2010/01/compile-gtk-2186-with-cygwin.html), which is exactly what I need, but I get an error when I run "make" for GTK2 (undefined reference for _IID_IFilePersist, although I have uuid installed - also tried it with gtk2.20). Can you suggest what to do to build my application with cygwin? Or what do I need to install for the "_IID_IFilePersist" error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There's prebuilt packages for windows that doesn't rely on X.  http://gtk-win.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/Downloads

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want X server to be running, then you're going to have to port the linux-specific parts of your code and compile with MinGW rather than Cygwin.

Comment: GTK can be compiled with cygwin, and it can be X independent. Just take a look at the lint in my post.